# Writing systemd unit file for suspend/resume

Tags: systemd, suspend

Every time i boot my system I enter

```
# su
Password:
# hciattach -s 152000 /dev/ttyS1 billionton
```

Thats needed for initializing my BT mouse
and
after resuming from suspend i have to enter following:

```
# su
Password:
```

Looking for hciattach PID and killing it

```
# pkill hciattach
# hciattach -s 152000 /dev/ttyS1 billionton
```

---

Now i have composed two scripts

```
# cat bt-mouse-suspend.service 
[Unit]
Description=BT Mouse suspend helper
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/pkill hciattach

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

---

```
# cat bt-mouse-resume.service 
[Unit]
Description=BT Mouse resume helper
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hciattach -s 152000 /dev/ttyS1 billionton

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
# systemctl status bt-mouse-resume
● bt-mouse-resume.service - BT Mouse resume helper
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bt-mouse-resume.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-04-03 22:09:50 EEST; 12min ago
 Main PID: 6386 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bt-mouse-resume.service

apr   03 22:09:50 Twinh systemd[1]: Started BT Mouse resume helper.
apr   03 22:09:51 Twinh hciattach[6386]: Device setup complete
# pgrep hciattach
#
```

Suspend script works well and kills what expected. But the resume hciattach once executed but becomes vanished after that.

Comment: @ddnomad Yes please check out my main post edit

Answer (score 2):

You've confused what `After` is referring to, `After` will cause a service to wait for another unit before it starts. Your `Wanted-By=suspend.target` and `After=suspend.target` contradict each other.

The `Wanted-By` is stating that `bt-mouse-resume.service` is a part of `suspend.target`, but the `After` is stating that `bt-mouse-resume.service` should wait until `suspend.target` is done. Services should not be a part of a target and wait for that target before starting. This also means you're configuring your service to run when `suspend.target` is started, rather than when it is exited.

What you're really looking for is a way to run something when stopping `suspend.target`, so I'll point you to a pretty important part of `systemd`:

> Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied.

[Reference](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=)

So you say your `bt-mouse-suspend.service` is working properly. Because of its `Wanted-By=sleep.target`, when `sleep.target` is started your service is run. Conversely, when `sleep.target` is stopped `bt-mouse-suspend.service` will be stopped as well. You should not require the `Before` field in this service, you are making your service an action of that target already.

So if you want to run `/usr/bin/hciattach -s 152000 /dev/ttyS1 billionton` when leaving `sleep.target`, make it the `ExecStop` for `bt-mouse-suspend.service`.

I'd also recommend some further reading on how `systemd` works, namely take a look at:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html#

Also, your two services target `suspend.target` and `sleep.target`. You should obviously use whichever target you're actually concerned with, but you're probably only looking for `suspend.target`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your are right but only problem reimained is that when hciattach executed by systemd service script, it immediately exits after service script ends. When i run hciattach manually, it stays alive. RemainAfterExit doesn't help, hciattach process still disappears.

Comment: did you modify the `bt-mouse-suspend.service` to have `ExecStop=/usr/bin/hciattach -s 152000 /dev/ttyS1 billionton`? If so, can you update your question?