# Script that is executed after resuming from hibernation?

Tags: shell-script, hibernate

There are things I would like the laptop to do after resuming from a disk hibernation.

In particular, I have it set at the lowest CPU frequency by default, which makes it absolutely silent (no fan noise at all) but still quick enough most of the time (I change the policy with another script when I really need more computing power). But, after resuming from a disk hibernation, the default factory behavior has been restored, which is a variable frequency and the damn fan firing up here and there in order to offer me the marvelous experience of opening programs a fraction of a second faster.

Remark: If anyone is curious about the script that sets the lowest CPU in my laptop (in case there's a better way to do this that is not affected by hibertate/resume), here it is:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -g userspace
sudo cpufreq-set -c 1 -g userspace
sudo cpufreq-set -c 2 -g userspace
sudo cpufreq-set -c 3 -g userspace
sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -f 400MHz
sudo cpufreq-set -c 1 -f 400MHz
sudo cpufreq-set -c 2 -f 400MHz
sudo cpufreq-set -c 3 -f 400MHz
```

And, by the way, this needs to disable *intel_pstate* in grub, which tells me that this feature is not going to be there in the future. Why the heck Intel doesn't like to allow me to have a silent and slow computer at times if that is my will, is a mistery to me.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your system you may be able to put an executable script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/00mysleep` which will be run with an argument saying what state is being entered: `suspend`, `hibernate`. `resume`, or `thaw`.

With systemd you should be able to put a script in, for example,
`/lib/systemd/system-sleep/00myscript` which will be run with 2 arguments,
the first being `pre` when stopping and `post` when resuming, and the second being the state, namely `suspend`, `hibernate`, or `hybrid-sleep`.

Or with systemd you can create and enable a Unit such as file `/etc/systemd/system/myscript.service` holding

```
[Unit]
Description=Run myscripttorun
After=suspend.target
#After=hibernate.target
#After=hybrid-sleep.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/some/path/myscripttorun
[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
#WantedBy=hibernate.target
#WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

enabled with

```
sudo systemctl enable myscript.service
```

Choose between the appropriate suspend, hibernate, hybrid-sleep targets by removing the `#` on the lines, and create a suitable script `/some/path/myscripttorun` to be run.

---

See also my more detailed [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620151/119298) to a similar question.

Comment: if my service generally runs all the time but needs to restart after resuming from suspend, which variation of this do I want?

Comment: If you already have a Unit set up and running, you probably can just add an extra `Restart=always` to the `[Service]` part, and it may get restarted when you come back from suspend, if it died. But you should post a new question with your specific details as it is a difficult subject in general.

Comment: According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355489/writing-systemd-unit-file-for-suspend-resume), `WantedBy` and `After` being the same is contradicting. `WantedBy` means it is part of that service while `After` means it should run after that service which is obviously impossible.

Comment: @StefanFabian There are some new, working examples on [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks).